# Can't add credentials.yml.enc file to VCS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubymine

I follow [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/capistrano.html#credentials) tutorial to deploy my rails application using capistrano and ruby-mine, one step required to generate encrypted credentials.yml.enc and add it to VCS, but I can't add it using ruby-mine even git add however the file is not present in gitignore file.

You find bellow content of gitignore file, the credentials.yml.enc is part of config directory

```
>> find . -name ".gitignore" -exec cat {} +

/shelf/
/workspace.xml
/dataSources/
/dataSources.local.xml
/httpRequests/
/sassc
/sass-spec

VERSION
.DS_Store
.sass-cache
*.gem
*.gcno
.svn/*
.cproject
.project
.settings/
*.db
*.aps

GNUmakefile.in
GNUmakefile
/aclocal.m4
/autom4te.cache/
/src/config.h
/config.h.in
/config.log
/config.status
/configure
/libtool
/m4/libtool.m4
/m4/ltoptions.m4
/m4/ltsugar.m4
/m4/ltversion.m4
/m4/lt~obsolete.m4
/script/ar-lib
/script/compile
/script/config.guess
/script/config.sub
/script/depcomp
/script/install-sh
/script/ltmain.sh
/script/missing
/script/test-driver
/src/stamp-h1
/src/Makefile.in
/src/Makefile
libsass/*

*.o
*.lo
*.so
*.dll
*.a
*.suo
*.sdf
*.opendb
*.opensdf
a.out
libsass.js
tester
tester.exe
build/
config.h.in*
lib/pkgconfig/

bin/*
.deps/
.libs/
win/bin
*.user
win/*.db

sassc++
libsass.la
src/support/libsass.pc

sassc/
sass-spec/

installer

.idea
/bin
/.bundle

/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal
/db/*.sqlite3-*

/log/*
/tmp/*
!/log/.keep
!/tmp/.keep

/tmp/pids/*
!/tmp/pids/
!/tmp/pids/.keep

/storage/*
!/storage/.keep

/public/assets
.byebug_history

/config/master.key

/public/packs
/public/packs-test
/node_modules
/yarn-error.log
yarn-debug.log*
.yarn-integrity
```

```
>> cat .gitignore

.idea
/bin
/.bundle

/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal
/db/*.sqlite3-*

/log/*
/tmp/*
!/log/.keep
!/tmp/.keep

/tmp/pids/*
!/tmp/pids/
!/tmp/pids/.keep

/storage/*
!/storage/.keep

/public/assets
.byebug_history

/config/master.key

/public/packs
/public/packs-test
/node_modules
/yarn-error.log
yarn-debug.log*
.yarn-integrity
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: could you show us the output of `find . -name ".gitignore" -exec cat {} +` from the root of the repository.

Comment: also the output of `cat ~/.gitignore`

Comment: I posted gitignore content

Comment: Interesting, could you do `git check-ignore credentials.yml.enc` and then `echo $?`?

Comment: the second one output 1

Comment: Well that means `git` is definitely not ignoring the file. 
I can't help you without any more information, we need some `git status` and `ls` to show the file and the git status along with it.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a possibility that the whole folder(and its
   subdirectories)/the extension **.enc is excluded in gitignore.
2. Is the file present when you look at `git status`. If yes, you'll
   need to `git add` the file before you do a `git commit`.
3. Is the file committed already, but not yet pushed?

These are some things on top of my head. Please post some more details to dig this up!